# Get back to previous ajax state from partial view form submission

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

I'm working on to add students with batches and before inserting recording I'm displaying partial view for transaction details with ajax call. This partial view submits a form through post action controller that inserts details for student's transaction details as well as inserts students with its batch. However I don't know how do i get back to my ajax previous state in the success response function.
Below is my code.

**Create.cshtml**

```
<script>
    $(".btn").click(function () {
        var Id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("AddStudentTransaction", "Student")',
            data: { SelectedId: Id },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (response)
            {
                // Want to get back here from partial view
                $('#dialog').html(response);
                $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                var tblEndrolled = $("#tblEnrolled");
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    var tr = $("<tr></tr>");
                    tr.html(("<td>" + '<input type="submit" id="' + item.Id + '" value="Remove" class="btn" />' + "</td>")
                    //+ " " + ("<td>" + item.Id + "</td>")
                    + " " + ("<td>" + item.FirstName + "</td>")
                    + " " + ("<td>" + item.LastName + "</td>")
                    + " " + ("<td>" + item.EmailAddress + "</td>")
                    + " " + ("<td>" + item.Phone + "</td>"));
                    tblEndrolled.append(tr);
                });
            }, failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**StudentController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult AddStudentTransaction(Models.StudentBatch student,string SelectedId)
{
    student.batchId = "30a547ad-ef04-41c4-95f8-60b37f004983";
    Context.Student contStud = new Context.Student();

    Context.Transaction contTrans = new Context.Transaction();
    Models.Transaction transaction = new Models.Transaction();
    transaction.lstTransactionMode = contTrans.GetTransactionMode();
    transaction.lstTransactionType = contTrans.GetTransactionTypes();
    transaction.UserId = SelectedId;
    ViewBag.BatchId = student.batchId;
    return PartialView("AddStudentTransaction", transaction);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateStudentWithTransaction(Models.Transaction transaction, string SelectedId, string id)
{
    try
    {
        transaction.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        string batchid = "30a547ad-ef04-41c4-95f8-60b37f004983";
        Context.Transaction contTransaction = new Context.Transaction();
        transaction.Date = DateTime.Now;
        bool result = contTransaction.AddTransaction(transaction);
        if (result == true)
        {
            Context.Student contStudent = new Context.Student();
            Models.StudentBatch student = new Models.StudentBatch();
            student.batchId = batchid;
            student.studentId = transaction.UserId;
            student.Transactionid = transaction.Id;
            student.RemainingAmount = "0";
            student.Status = "Clear";
            contStudent.AddNewStudentBatch(student);
            CreateUser user = new CreateUser();
            var StudentList = user.GetAllUsers().ToList().Where(u => u.Id == transaction.UserId);
            ViewBag.Value = StudentList;
        }
        // TODO: Add insert logic here
        return Json(ViewBag.Value, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        //return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**AddStudentTransaction.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateStudentWithTransaction", "Student", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    // all the required controls
}
```

**StudentController.cs**

Comment: What do you mean _get back to my ajax previous state_? And what is `data` in your `$.each(data, function (index, item) {` loop?

Comment: And what does you `CreateStudentWithTransaction()` method have to do with your question?

Comment: Getting back to success response state on ajax method from where i loaded partial view. and data should contains Viewbag value as coded in CreateStudentWithTransaction controller action.

Comment: No where in your script are you calling the `CreateStudentWithTransaction()` method. The only place its called is when you submit the form, but that makes no sense because that method returns json. Its hard to understand what your trying to do.

Comment: yes, the partial view form is submitted. And as soon as the form submits i want to get back to the previous page, but on the ajax response from where i left, so that i can print records in the form of table.

Comment: Sorry, but your comment (particularly the _but on the ajax response from where i left_) is not making any sense. You have not shown your 'current' view or what it displays, but I can only assume that your `CreateStudentWithTransaction()` should be redirecting back to that view.

Comment: altight, for instance i load a partial view through ajax call but after all process i want the result response on the same ajax. How do i get back to my previous page?